# Asynchronous HttpWebRequest is Disabling GUI on WP8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, asynchronous, request, windows-phone-8.1

I have a problem when I'm Sending and Receiving HttpWebRequests and Responses. My current code will disable the GUI of the phone when I start the call. I have read over many questions, but I cannot figure out how to change my code to not disable the GUI and still obtain the data.

Here is my code:

```
    public static string Data = "null";

    private static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        public void SendRequest(string Url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Url);
        myRequest.Method = "GET";
        myRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallBack), myRequest);


        allDone.WaitOne();



    }

    private void GetResponseCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;

        // End the operation
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(ar);
        Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
        string responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
        streamResponse.Dispose();
        streamRead.Dispose();

        Data = responseString;

        response.Dispose();        


        allDone.Set();

    }
```

I'm calling this from the MainPage.xaml.cs button event handler. What I want to do is change a textbox (or some other control) to be filled with the data that I get returned from this method. I need the textbox to update once the data is received... Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ManualResetEvent.WaitOne` blocks the thread in waiting for `ManualResetEvent.Set`.

Just remove the ManualResetEvent and update the TextBlock from `GetResponseCallBack`. To update it you'll need something like this (because the callback is not invoked in the UI thread):

```
//Windows Phone 8.0:
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate() {
    //Update UI here
});

//Windows Phone 8.1:
CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, delegate() {
    //Update UI here
});
```

Another option is to make the `SendRequest` method async using [Task.Factory.FromAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) or [TaskCompletionSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dd449174%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

**Update**

You may want to check out the [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpclient.aspx) class. It is like a new async version of the HttpWebRequest. I think that's the way to go.

Comment: @user3138251 It's System.Windows.Deployment. Does that work? This is not in WP8.1, right? Also, I edited my answer and added another idea of how to resolve it.

Comment: Am I unable to do this in Windows Phone 8.1? @yasen

Comment: @user3138251 I added the info for WP8.1.

Comment: Alright, sorry, I'm really new to Async things... So I'm getting this warning "Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call." I'm not sure how to fix this...

Comment: @user3138251 warnings don't need to be fixed :) You can make the method `async` and then add the `await` keyword in front of RunAsync, but I think it's okay to leave it as it is. Also, I added some more info to the answer - check out HttpClient. And it'll be good if you read a little about asynchronous programming - it's just too much for me to put in an answer, and it's important to know about it.

Comment: Okay thank you so much, one last question: What do I need to put inside the "Dispatcher.RunAsync" brackets to actually update the textbox back on the MainPage.xaml? I cannot figure this out...

Comment: @user3138251 Are these two methods in the page's .xaml.cs file? If so, you need to do this: set the TextBlock's x:Name in the .xaml file to something like "MyText", and then in that line type `this.MyText.Text = "updated text!";`. If not... well you'll need to get the instance of the page somehow.

Comment: @user3138251 Glad I could help. :) Maybe we should delete these comments now, as they may not be very useful to others?

Comment: One thing to remember. When you dont `await` on your async operation and an exception occurs it will unobserved and swallow by the `Task`